# TCP wireless communication

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, sockets

For the pass 2 months, i am trying to establish a wireless communication between 2 devices. Whatever solution i found, got failed due to large number of constraints we have. Seriously posting this question after huge disappointment. Could anyone help? Please? 
My major constraint is the coverage area for this wireless connection should be 5km. So i ruled out WLAN from my solution list. Then i tried with socket programming over internet, making server-client kinda setup. But that worked only when i tried with wired LAN. 
When i tried to used it over internet i faced loads of difficulties. First came port forwarding, but that wasnt so difficult, as i learned to do it eventually. But major threat is Carrier grade NAT. I am doing this project in india but i have to show a demo in france and i dont know nothing about their service providers. My whole project objective is about something else, but we stuck with this for nearly 2 months. We just need to transfer less than 1kb char data between 2 sytems wirelessly over 5 km. If you could share your valuable thoughts, it will be very useful to me. Please. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Carrier grade NAT.

You have three choices.

- Talk to your ISP and see if they offer a (potentially expensive) account with a public IP.
- Use IPv6 if your ISP supports it.
- Have an externally reachable intermediate system with a real public IP (VPS, etc.) that you can use to facilitate communication between the two nodes (this can be something you write, etc.)

The third solution will likely be the best if you don't know anything about the ISPs involved when you get to France.

Comment: I too have it as last option. Hosting a middle man server in india.

Answer (score 1):

Use socket programming over the Internet. But have both endpoints connect to a "relay" server hosted with a reliable hosting service using HTTPS. NAT shouldn't prevent HTTPS from working outbound.

Comment: while referring to relay server, are you talking about mail servers? please clarify.

Comment: No, I'm not talking about mail servers. I'm talking about a server using HTTPS that relays messages between the machines. You could use existing chat software if you really wanted to.